# Server 14.04.3 LTS Display Orientation

Tags: display, xrandr, rotate, orientation

I'm pretty new to Ubuntu but I am currently trying to use a server version to display an application for a stripped down kiosk. I've got Ubuntu booting up into the application I want at startup, however I've run into one issue. I need to change the display orientation from Landscape to Portrait.

So far I haven't had much success and I've searched through the google a bunch without anything working for me. I thought I'd ask here. From my understanding I should be using the `xrandr` command.

What I've tried so far is:

`xrandr` which tells me that it Can't open disaply

`xrandr -d :0` which gives me the following output

```
xrandr: Output HDMI1 is not disconnected but has no modes
xrandr: Output HDMI1 is not disconnected but has no modes
xrandr: Output VIRTUAL1 is not disconnected but has no modes
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1680 x 1050, maximum 32767 x 32767
VGA1 connected 1680x1050+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 490mm x 320mm 1680x1050 59.9**
HDMI1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 
VIRTUAL1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

From that I figure I should do something like:

`xrandr --output VGA1 --rotate left`

However, that responds with Can't open display.

I've tried a few other things but I'm really at a loss here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Which desktop environment/window manager are you using (if any?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to specify the display to modify/use, using `-d` again (or `--screen`?):

```
xrandr --output VGA1 --rotate normal -d :0
```

Note that this needs to be done with the display focused on the screen, otherwise it may throw a error like `xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed` (e.g. when doing the commands from a TTY) - to fix this the display needs to be focused when the command is run, so for instance with a TTY you could use this command and switch back to the GUI quickly:

```
sleep 5; xrandr --output VGA1 --rotate normal -d :0
```

Also, desktop environments often include display settings, you may be able to do this from there.

Comment: Thank you so much Wilf! You are awesome. I've added this to the script that starts up my application and now it does it automatically!

Thanks again!

Comment: Hey Wilf, I'm hoping you have another quick answer for me. I've switched from using VGA to HDMI.

Now whenever I use xrandr -d :0 it just tells me "Can't Open Display" no mater what I put after it. Any ideas?

Thanks again!

Comment: It may be under a different display number (e.g. `1` - probably depends on graphic cards and stuff) - you should be able to see this by running `echo $DISPLAY`, or looking at the output of the `w` command

Comment: `echo $DISPLAY` gave me a blank response and with `w` I'm not sure what I'm looking for. I was about to go through different display numbers by trial and error (I think I had tried that before without success) and for no apparent reason `xrandr -d :0` output properly this time.

Thanks for the replies! You're the best. I wonder how long this will work for...